# Handling multiple filters in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat to render a complex set of data in the UI. After receiving the data, I need to filter the data based on some checkboxes, sliders etc. Right now I will have 6 custom filters, based on time, price, and some checkboxes. I am using them like following

```
ng:repeat="response in searchResponse|filter:filter1(response)|filter:filter2(response)|filter:filter3(response)|filter:filter4(response)|filter:filter5(response)|filter:filter6(response)|limitTo:totalDisplayed
```

This works fine but I think this is a very expensive way of applying filters. I have noticed a considerable lag in performance in rendering after this. Is there a better way to handle filters here ? Considering the fact that I may have more such filters in future.

Please suggest. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of chaining filters, why not something like:

```
ng:repeat="response in searchResponse|filter:genericFilter(response, filterConditions)|limitTo:totalDisplayed
```

What you're doing is like chaining filters one after another, and that may not necessarily be needed – one filter that selects out the results based on `filterConditions`

Comment: Yes, chaining filters is not good. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: In my case, filterCondition will be changed by another function, how would I apply the filter in that case ? Do I need to call the genericFilter again from the controller somehow ?

Comment: You can bind conditions using `ngModel`, and then use whatever is the model as the condition – or a collection of using models as a combined condition.
Something in the lines of 
`<input ng-model="searchsomething"></input>` and then that model is accessible in the filter to be used as `filterCondition` or a part of it. I'd suggest you read up about `ngModel`

Comment: So basically all the filter conditions I had were being executed initially for all the data which was not required. This was causing additional time while rendering the data. I have added a flag in filters to not apply them for the first time. I have kept the chained filters as they are for now. Thanks anyways, you made me think more in the right direction :)